Show that the simple functions are dense in $L^2[a,b]$
So I am not sure if my proof is right. 
My attempt: Let $f \in L^2$ then $f= f^+ -f^-$. Now $f^+$ and $f^-$ are nonnegetive measurable functions. So they can be approximated by simple functions $\phi^+$ and $\phi^-$. So,
$$\left( \int |f^+-\phi^+|^2dx \right)^{1/2}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
\left( \int |f^--\phi^-|^2dx \right)^{1/2}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
Now,
$$
\left( \int |f-\phi|^2dx \right)^{1/2}=\left( \int |f^++f^--\phi^++\phi^-|^2dx \right)^{1/2}=\left( \int |(f^+-\phi^+)+(\phi^--f^-)|^2dx \right)^{1/2}\\\leq\left( \int |f^+-\phi^+|^2dx\right)^{1/2}+\left( \int |f^--\phi^-|^2dx\right)^{1/2}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon
$$
Is that the correct way to do it?

"So they can be approximated by simple functions $\phi^+$ and $\phi^-$. So $\int\lvert f^+-\phi^+\rvert^2,dx<\frac\epsilon2$..." - What exactly is the statement, and why is it true?

You can use orthogonality. If $f$ is orthogonal to all indicator functions of subintervals $[a,b]$ then $f=0.$
